# The styles and javascript files aren't showing when deploy Django application to a2hosting CPanel

Tags: django, cpanel

I've deployed my Django application to the **a2hosting** web hosting the styles aren't showing. Also, the page that has swagger documentation is blank and doesn't have anything.
Here in the image, you can see how the **Admin page** is showing.
[admin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5HJN.png)

I've made **collectstatic** and here is the setting.py configurations:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: Django don't serve the static files in production. You need to add stuff / a route / to the http server (like Apache or Nginx) Google: `django serving static files with {your http server}`

Comment: @Nealium I've followed this article: 
http://www.django.co.zw/en/tutorials/managing-static-files-with-django-on-a-shared-server/
but it still doesn't work

Comment: doesn't* ..that's a weird tutorial. How you running the Django Server?- just with `python manage.py runserver`?? - also here are the Django docs that a generally used for Static files in a Production environment https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-the-site-and-your-static-files-from-the-same-server